Setting Up Nuxt 3 on Apache Server alongside Laravel and Custom Package
I'm a frontend developer with limited experience in web servers, virtual hosts, server configurations, etc. I'm currently working on a project that has a backend built with Laravel. On the frontend, I would like to integrate Nuxt 3, but I'm encountering multiple errors during the server configuration process.
The server I'm using is already set up with Apache (because of Laravel) and is managed via Virtualmin, running on Rocky Linux 8. The project also connects to a custom package located in the packages/myproject/ecommerce directory, which is outside of the main project folder.
My goal is to use Nuxt 3 in this package so that when I request a URL from the myproject, it returns views from the package using Nuxt 3.
Could anyone help guide me through the process of configuring this properly? Specifically, how can I configure the server to serve the Nuxt 3 frontend from the package while keeping Laravel and Apache as they are?
Any detailed advice or configuration examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
